# Using CloudFormation::Init to copy local .zip to newly created EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-macro

I created a Webserver stack with an EC2 instance and I am trying to deploy a local artifact to the EC2 instance using CloudFormation::Init

I tried simply referencing the local file `website.zip` under `sources:` and running `cloudformation package`, but unfortunately it only recognizes and uploads [specific resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html) to S3.

```
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        config:
          packages:
            yum:
              npm: []
          sources:
            /home/ec2-user/developer-site: applications/website.zip
```

I also tried using `AWS::Include` in combination with `cloudformation package`, but `AWS ::Include` substitutes the raw contents of the file rather than simply the s3 url.

Is there another way around this? Is it possible to create my own macro for replacing [local url] with [s3 url] under Metadata sources? It seems like such a useful feature, I can't imagine it not being possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do it is a two-step.  Upload the ZIPs to the S3 bucket with the CloudFormation template.  Ensure the EC2 instance has the correct role to access the zip file in the S3 bucket.  In the EC2 CloudFormation section, use the userdata section to run script to issue aws s3 cp commands to get the zip file into S3.  Bonus!  You can also unzip it and do all kinds of other things.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @Christian. Could you elaborate on how to "Upload the ZIPs to the S3 bucket with the CloudFormation template" ? That proved very challenging, since there is no native `AWS::Bucket::Object` resource and I cannot reference external files on a CloudFormation template (except through sam package, which is limited to some resources). My approach was to include the zip within a Lambda `Code` directory and then use the lambda itself to upload the package to S3, returning the S3 url in a custom resource (which works, but feels very hacky). I'm hoping I'm overthinking it.

Comment: My thought is that the CloudFormation template and its contents (files, ZIPs, etc.) also be present in the shared CFN bucket.  So the bucket has the Cloud Formation template for the EC2 instance and the ZIP file that will be referenced.  Setup a new Cloud Formation instance pointing to your CF Template in the S3 Bucket.  This will spin up the EC2 instance which has been granted permission to access this S3 bucket.  The userdata script will call an aws s3 cp command to pull the zip local to the EC2 and work with it.  You don't need to use S3 for the zip;the userdata could wget it form anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Christian. The only other suggestion would be to use CDK which allow you to bundle assets and upload in one operation. It may be overkill for what you are thinking. SAM and AWS CLI both have options to bundle assets but neither of them support doing that for AWS::CloudFormation::Init at this time.  https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2862